# CallKit com.apple.CallKit.error.calldirectorymanager error 1

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I am using callkit to identify phone number.

It gives me error : `The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.CallKit.error.calldirectorymanager error 1.)`

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let numbers = ["94XXXXXXX"]
    let labels = ["TestUser"]
    writeFileForCallDirectory(numbers: numbers, labels: labels)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
fileprivate func writeFileForCallDirectory(numbers: [String], labels: [String]) {
    guard let fileUrl = FileManager.default
        .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.CallKit.CallBlock")?
        .appendingPathComponent("contacts") else { return }

    var string = ""
    for (number, label) in zip(numbers, labels) {
        string += "\(number),\(label)\n"
    }

    try? string.write(to: fileUrl, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
    //CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance.reloadExtension(withIdentifier: "group.com.CallKit.CallBlock")

    CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance.reloadExtension(withIdentifier: "group.com.CallKit.CallBlock", completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })


}
```

App group is enable to share data between app and extension but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using app group for the reloadExtension.

Use your bundle identifier of your callkit extension.

Comment: This answer is correct.   error code 1 is documented as "extension not found" - if you indeed have an extension running, you are using the wrong name to reload it.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxerrorcodecalldirectorymanagererror/code/noextensionfound